# Script to move files that match part of anther files name

Tags: windows-7, shell-script

I am trying to figure out how to write a script that will take files like this:

```
img123
img123back
img124
img125
img125back
img126
img127
```

I need to move all the files that have the same number as the files with the word “back” to a separate folder. Example of results:

```
img123
img123back
img125
img125back
```

Comment: Rob - Did you get a chance to test with the answer I provided below yet? See [Accepting an Answer](https://i.imgur.com/OZho1tT.png) to ensure you understand how that works for the solution you find for any answers that help you resolve your problem by simply checking the little gray check box to the upper left side of the answer that resolves your problem assuming one does and turn it green to show it's the answer you accepted since that's how that is supposed to work; you ask a question, you get answers, and if you get an answer that works for your needs, you simply accept that answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [for /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) to iterate the output of the [dir](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) command against the source directory. You can use some conditional [if](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) logic and for loop variable substitutions to confirm that the files with the single string "back" exists, and if it does you then copy that file and the file with the same name minus the string accordingly.

```
@ECHO ON

SET "srcPath=C:\Source\Path"
SET "destPath=C:\Copy\Path"
SET "keyword=back"

FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%A IN ('DIR /B /A-D "%srcPath%\*"') DO (
    IF EXIST "%%~DPA%%~NA%keyword%%%~XA" XCOPY /Y /F "%%~DPA%%~NA%keyword%%%~XA" "%destPath%\" & XCOPY /Y /F "%%~FNXA" "%destPath%\"
    )
PAUSE
EXIT
```

---

### Further Resources

- [For /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- [Dir](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)
- [If](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- **Batch Substitutions (FOR /?)**

  > In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been
  >   enhanced. You can now use the following optional syntax:
  >
  > ```
  > %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
  > %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
  > %~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
  > %~pI        - expands %I to a path only
  > %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
  > %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
  > ```
- [XCopy](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html)
- [Redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)